# VBA Change ARIA-Controls Value

Tags: html, vba, excel, wai-aria

Good Morning,

I am trying to use VBA to fill an online form that uses "Aria". The program is very simple, and works for any form that doesn't use Aria, however I'm having a hard time adjusting it to this site. The HTML is as follows:

`<div class="selectwrapper">
    <label class="has-float-label shadow" for "event-0-line-0-name">
        <div class="react-autosuggest__container" role="combobox" aria-expand ="false" aria-haspopup="listbox" aria-owns="react-autowhatever-event-0-line-0-name">
            <input class="react-autosuggest__input" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-event-0-line-0-name" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" placehold="" autocomplete="off" value = "" />
            <div class="react-autosuggest__suggestions-container" id="react-autowhatever-event-0-line-0-name" role="listbox" value="VALUE FROM PROGRAM">`

Currently I'm using `.getElementByID`, and `.setAttribute("value", "random text")`. In the HTML this does change the value of the ID, however on the form it is still blank. I think I have to change the value under aria-controls, but I'm not sure how to do this in VBA. (When I change the Value under Aria-Controls manually, it updates on the form.

I'm hoping this is an easy fix, I'm guessing I just have to change the `.getElementByID` to something else, but I'm not sure what that is. Any help is will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

> Currently I'm using `.getElementByID`, and `.setAttribute("value",
>   "random text")`. In the HTML this does change the value of the ID

I don't follow what you're saying here.  Setting the "`value`" attribute will not change the ID.

> I think I have to change the value under aria-controls, but I'm not
>   sure how to do this in VBA.

ARIA attributes are just like any other attribute and can be changed with `setAttribute`.  For example to change the `aria-expanded` attribute, do this:

```html
setAttribute('aria-expanded', 'true');
```

However, changing the ARIA attributes won't affect your form.  ARIA attributes are hints to screen readers and other assistive technology and their values don't affect the visual display.

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to say I'm trying to change the Value of the ID. I just meant that in the HTML, there are 2 Values. One I was designating as the ID Value, and one as the aria-controls ID. (Just using those names because ID and aria-controls are both named react-autowhatever-event-0-line-0-name). When I use .getElementByID, it changes the Value under the ID. I'm trying to change the value under Aroa-Controls. I hope this clears things up, thank you!

Comment: did you already try `setAttribute('aria-controls', 'new list of ids');`?  as mentioned, `aria-controls` is no different than any other html attribute and its value can be set from javascript.  or, are you trying to get to the object referenced by the ID in `aria-controls` and change that object's value?

Comment: The second one, under the HTML: <input class="react-autosuggest__input" aria-controls="react-autowhatever-event-0-line-0-name" aria-autocomplete="list" type="text" placehold="" autocomplete="off" value = "" />, I'm trying to change the actual Value

Comment: so you get the value of `aria-controls` and use that value in a subsequent `getElementByID()` to get the object it's pointing to.  you can then change anything you want on the subsequent object.